# force row selection in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection

I got a p:dataTable which contains

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" widgetVar="dataTableCar" var="category"
value="#{CategoryBean.categories}" selection="#{CategoryBean.selectedCategory}"
selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{category}"                 
    <p:column headerText="name">
       <h:outputText value="#{category.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="parent">
       <p:autoComplete id="parentCategory" completeMethod="#{CategoryBean.categories}" maxResults="20" value="#{category.parent}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}"
  itemValue="#{p}" converter="#{categoryStringConverter}"
  forceSelection="true">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
     listener="#{CategoryBean.oncategorySelect}" />
        </p:autoComplete>
    </p:column>
```

I need to force a row selection in case the user clicks into the autocomplete. Maybe I should mention if the user clicks into a ui control (in this example it is the autocomplete) which is hosted by the p:column, there will be no row selected.

Is there a way to implement this? If I don't get the selected row, I can't process the parent category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Do this by 2 ways, both Include Jquery.

I will use the following `p:dataTable` code to show both the ways.
I'm using `h:inputText` instead of `p:autoComplete` .

```
<p:dataTable value="#{userManagedBean.userList}" var="user" 
                    selection="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single"
                    rowKey="#{user.email}" widgetVar="dataTableWidget">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"/>

            <p:column headerText="Email">
                #{user.email}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" onclick="myFunction(this);"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

**First Way:**

When ever user clicks on the Autocomplete simulate the click event on its parent, in this case its `<td>`, so which in turn selects its parent `<tr>` and finally your Row will get selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(ele){
    var tdEle = $(ele).parent();
    $(tdEle).click();
   }
</script>
```

**Second Way**

This by using the Primefaces client side API function `selectRow(r,flag)`, which will be called on `p:dataTable`'s `widgetWar` object.
Here `selectRow(r,flag)` will take 2 paramenters:

- `r` is Jquery Row element () of the row which needs to be selected.
- `flag` is Boolean which specifies ajax select or not.

so now My Javascript function for this would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(ele){
        var tdEle = $(ele).parent();
        var trEle = $(tdEle).parent();
        dataTableWidget.selectRow($(trEle),true); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hello, i create the follow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277267/identify-when-the-selected-row-in-the-table-is-already-selected .

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

for example : 
In your datatble with primefaces you have the "onChange" in one of the columns

> value="#{r.visualizaUnicoTodo}" styleClass="chk-nty pd" 
>                                                                                        onchange="check_edit(this)">

To select the current item clicked

```
 var check_edit = function (id) {
            console.info("Id Elemento Checkeado :" + id);
            console.info("Verificar si esta seleccionado : : " + $(id).is(':checked'));
}
```